# Using a Wildcard Match as a Command Line Argument in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, command-line, wildcard

I'm trying to write a Bash script to convert a bunch of files.

Assume I have a directory `/path/to/my files/` with three text files: `a b.txt`, `c d.txt` and `e.txt` (note the spaces)

I need to be able to call the script like this:

```
$ ./myscript.sh /path/to/my\ files/*.txt
```

and then loop through them in bash to process them like this:

```
dest='/desktop/'
for ARG in $@; do
  /some/other/script $ARG $dest$ARG.new
done
```

It doesn't have to work exactly like this, whatever is easiest that will yield similar results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this do what you need:

```
dest='/desktop/'
for ARG in "$@"; do
  /some/other/script "$ARG" "$dest$ARG.new"
done
```

EDIT:  To remove the path on ARG

```
dest='/desktop/'
for ARG in "$@"; do
  /some/other/script "$ARG" "$dest$(basename "$ARG").new"
done
```

Comment: The `"$@"` got me halfway there. Ideally, I'd like $ARG to have just the filename so that `$dest$ARG` doesn't have a huge path. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: You can even shorten it to `for ARG;` - That uses `$@` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Bash does wildcard expansion before executing the command, that is, it will replace that expression with a list of matching files.